# All possible assignment vectors of 2n users

Tags: python

I would like to write a function to calculate all possible assignment vectors of 2n users, where n users are assigned to group 0 (control), and n users are assigned to group 1 (treatment).

I've tried a recursive approach as you can see below, but I know it can not work like this (I should have C(2n,n) vectors I think, right?)

Any ideas?

Thanks.

```
def algo(n):
   T = list();
   if n>=2 :
      for j in range(len(algo(n-1))/2):
         T.append([0,1]+algo(n-1)[j]);
      for j in range(len(algo(n-1))/2):
         T.append([1,0]+algo(n-1)[j]);
      for j in (len(algo(n-1)/2):(len(algo(n-1)*(3/4)):
         T.append([0,0]+algo(n-1)[j]);    
      for j in range(len(algo(n-1))):
         T.append([1,1]+algo(n-1)[j]);
   if n==1 :
      T=[[0,1],[1,0],[0,0],[1,1]];
   return T
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import itertools

def split_users(users_list):
    users = set(users_list)
    for comb in itertools.combinations(users, int(len(users)/2)):
        control = set(comb)
        treatment = users - control
        yield control, treatment

users = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}

for control, treatment in split_users(users):
    print "Control", control, "treatment", treatment
```

In two words: `split_users` is a generator function that takes all possible combinations of `count_of_users/2` elements out of users list, assigns them to `control` group and then treats all the rest as `treatment` group.

Refer to [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [yield](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) documentation for details.

Also, please note that whatever you mean by "user" need to be hashable. So, if users are represented as custom class you need to define [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) and [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) function.

Comment: OK Thanks. So I realize now that my problem is almost equivalent to the one that consists to sort a set of value in lexicographic order.

Answer (score 1):

## Idea 1: Use existing functions in python

## Idea 2: Use a recursive approach to do it.

```
def allSamples(k,n):
    # choose k elements in candidate lists from [0,...,n-1] with length n
    # input:
        # k: number of choosed elements 
        # n: candidate list length
    # output: 
        # list of all possible assignments

    allC = []

    if k == 1:
        for i in range(n):
            assignment = [0]*n
            assignment[i] = 1
            allC.append(assignment)
    elif n == k:
        assigment = [1]*n
        allC = [assigment]
    else:
        pl = n - k + 1
        for i in range(pl):
            assignment = [0]*(i+1)
            assignment[i] = 1
            for c in allSamples(k-1,n-i-1):
                allC.append(assignment+c)
    return allC

k = 2
n = 2*k
print allSamples(k,n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive approach works very well:

```
def iter_fun(sum, deepness, myString, currentI, Total):
    if deepness == 0:
    print myString
    else:    
    for i in xrange(currentI+1, Total): 
        iter_fun(sum + 1,deepness - 1,myString + str(i),i,Total) 

def enumeratePartition(digits, Tot):
    iter_fun(0,digits,"",-1,Tot) 


enumeratePartition(4,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Binary :)

```
def binSum(n):
    st = str(bin(n))
    sum = 0;
    i = 2
    while i < len(st):
        sum += int(st[i])
        i += 1
    return sum

def assignmentVectors(n):
    for i in range(0,pow(2,n)-1):
        if binSum(i) == n/2:
            print ('{:0'+str(n)+ 'b}').format(i)

assignmentVectors(4)
assignmentVectors(6)
assignmentVectors(8)
```

Comment: `sum` is a built in function, so you shouldn't use it as a variable name. And you should be a bit more specific explaining why this works. "Use Binary" is very vague.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to produce your assignment like this:

```
from itertools import product

n=3
values = [0,1]
ref_list = [values]*2*n

for p in product(*ref_list):
    if sum(p) == n:
        print(p)
```